# Date pivot table creation

Tags: sql

I have a Bank transaction table with multiple dates, I want to create a pivot table out of it based on dates, but the number of visits is not predetermined, So I want to make the pivot table dynamic, as new transaction comes it should add new column saying visit 4,5,6,and so on and add corresponding amount in the row.

Comment: dynamic pivot = dynamic sql  so this will depend a lot on your specific rdbms (sql-server, oracle, mysql....) so tag appropriately. Also if you want any kind of useful help on this you will need to add some example data and desired result.  Next give it a try!  look up how to pivot data and then dynamic sql and try combining them

Comment: To piggy back off of Matt, here would be a good place to start for SQL Server. http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/  try something and ask for help if you fail